# Does a non-current private pilot need to renew his license to obtain a Part 107 (Remote Pilot) certification?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am a non current private pilot (haven't flown for about 15 years) that need a 107 license for work to fly DJI drones.

my employer is not going to pay around $1,000 to get me current again (it's been a while. I will need some ground school and some practice to get to my groove).

Can I just take the 107 course and only get the remote pilot? or since I'm a pilot now, I need to make my private pilot current as well?

Comment: I would suggest contacting the FAA at https://www.faa.gov/uas/contact_us. They can provide the proper guidance.

Answer (score 4):

See 14 CFR 107.61(d).

If you do not meet the flight review requirement of 61.56, then you do not qualify to get a Remote Pilot License by taking the training described in 107.73.

However, you can still get one by passing the knowledge test described in 107.74, same as a non-pilot.